# ER Diagram for my Knowledge Base

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I want to create a Knowledge Base for me (related to tech solutions).

It is simple, I am thinking in: ARTICLE and TAG entities. An article contain one or many tags. An tag is contained by 0 or many articles. "contain" relationship is N:M (a new table in the Relational Model).

This is the idea, example: After a few hours I find a solution for "Windows Update stuck for Windows 7 SP1". Then I create an article with that solution and I tag it with "Windows", "Windows 7 SP1", "Windows Update". And to find something I will create a searcher to filter by tags, title, content, a mix, ... I do not know yet.

Do I need more ENTITIES? It is ONLY for me, so I am the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

As one article can have one or more tags, you will need a join table. Such a table would have two fields: one foreign key for articles and one foreign key for tags. Thus your design requires three tables: articles, tags and 'tag2article'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have a third table, like I said "'contain' relationship is N:M (a new table in the Relational Model).". In ER Diagram, it is a relationship N:M -equal to a new table- between ARTICLE and TAG entities. Like you said: "would have two fields: one foreign key for articles and one foreign key for tags".